# How to hide a custom attribute to category on particular category level?

Tags: category, attributes, adminhtml, magento-1, adminform

I have created a custom attribute for the categories using installer script.

But I want to show that attribute only on level two categories.For all other levels it should not be visible.( This attribute is not mandatory field )

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'short_name', array(
    'group'                    => 'General Information',
    'input'                    => 'text',
    'type'                     => 'varchar',
    'label'                    => 'Short Category Name',
    'visible'                  => true,
    'required'                 => false,
    'visible_on_front'         => true,
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
    'global'                   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
));
```

[image: Screenshot of requirement]

Is it possible to hide it from specific levels ? 
I mean by hide that it should not be visible.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a custom renderer. In the install script, add something like:

```
'input_renderer' => 'stack_category/custom_renderer'
```

And create a block class like:

```
class Stack_Category_Block_Custom_Renderer extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Text
{
    public function getHtml()
    {
        if (Mage::registry('current_category')->getLevel() == 2) {
            return parent::getHtml();
        }
        return '';
    }
}
```